Command Line for opening RTC Eclipse Client 6.0.2 with a specific username and password file
My command line for opening RTC Eclipse Client is:
"C:\Program Files\IBM\TeamConcert\eclipse.exe" -product com.ibm.team.concert.product

Can I add anything on the end of the command line to automatically log in to RTC as a specific username using the password file I use for scm.exe?
